# Embedded jpeg showing in svg, but not in pdf when generated with svglib, reportlab

Tags: python, django, pdf, svg

I'm using version 0.6.3 of svglib and reportlab 2.5.
I created the test svg in Inkscape; placed one jpeg in it, embedded with base64.

When I step in the code, the jpeg gets generated in svglib, but it never shows up in pdf.

Vector shapes work fine and get shown, but jpeg is missing. I was using the basic command in terminal (svg2pdf) for testing.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem?

**EDIT:**
SVG code, as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="744"
height="1052"
id="svg2"
version="1.1">
<defs
id="defs4" />
<rect width="1000" height="1000"
style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;
stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
<image
y="378"
x="282"
id="image2993"
xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk... snip snip .../9k="
height="307"
width="186" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a little more detail this is tough to answer, the most common mistake, though, when including images is not including the namespace:

```
<image href="someurlgoeshere" x="0" y="0" height="10" width="10"></image>
```

vs

```
<image xlink:href="someurlgoeshere" x="0" y="0" height="10" width="10"></image>
```

Comment: I have the namespace (the lower example is correct) so no problem there.

Comment: When you say you're using base64 I assume you're using a dataurl. Does it start something like this: `xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,abunchofbasesixtyfourstuffgoeshere"`

Comment: Could you post the SVG code?  There are a number of other common areas where problems in SVG->PDF arise.